# Find the acceleration of a particle and its maximum speed

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I study maths for a hobby and am stuck with this problem:

A particle moves in a straight line such that after t seconds its displacement from a fixed point is s metres, where $s = 4\cos t - \cos2 t$. If the particle first comes to rest after T seconds, where $T \gt 0$, find (a) its acceleration at time T, (b) the maximum speed it attains for $0 \lt t \lt T$

My working is as follows:

$s = 4\cos t - \cos2t$

let V = velocity and A = acceleration

$V = \frac{ds}{dt} = 2\sin 2t - 4\sin t$

$A = \frac{dV}{dt} = 4\cos 2t - 4\cos t$

V = 0 when $2 \sin 2t = 4\sin t$

Now, $\sin2 t = 2\sin t\cos t$

So V = 0 when $4\sin t \cos t = 4 \sin t$

$\cos t = \frac{4\sin t}{4\sin t} = 1$

When I substitute this into my equation for acceleration I get 0.

The book says the answers are (a) 8 m/sec (b)$3\sqrt3 $ m/sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, when $v = 0$, $\sin t \cos t =  \sin t$.

This is true when $\sin t = 0 \,$.

So the first time when it happens is when $t = 0$ as $\sin t = 0$. But we need to find the first time $T$ it comes to rest for $t \gt 0$.

$\sin t = 0 \,$ when $t = \pi$.

Please note when $\cos t = 1, $ $\sin t = 0$ but if you go by $\cos t = 1$ that only happens at $t = 2\pi \,$ for $t \gt 0$.

Now if you plug in $t = \pi$, you get the acceleration.

Also for max speed $|v_{max}|$, set $\frac{dV}{dt} = 0$. That gives you,

$\cos 2t = \cos t \implies 2cos^2t - \cos t - 1 = 0$

i.e. $(2\cos t + 1) (\cos t - 1) = 0$

That leads to only one possible point $t = \frac{2 \pi}{3}$ for $0 \lt t \lt T$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$ 4\sin t\cos t = 4\sin t$  implies either $\cos t=1 $ or $\sin t =0$

The smallest $t>0$ satisfying this is $t=\pi$ in which case $\cos 2t=1$ and $\cos t = -1$, leading to $A=8$

For (b), maximum velocity occurs when acceleration is $0$ and is changing from positive to negative